# how do I deploy my Airflow Scheduler to AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, airflow, amazon-emr

I'm trying to build a simple data pipeline on AWS using Airflow.
I've created a DAG that scrapes data to S3 daily and then processes it with a Spark Job running on EMR.

I'm currently running the Airflow Scheduler on my laptop locally,but of course I know this isn't a good long term solution.

So I wanted to have some tips on deploying my scheduler to EC2 (istance size,deploying process or anything else it would be useful to know)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running locally is usually not a feasible post test phase. So you need a running server. Following can be the options and guide for deploying it to AWS EC2.

You can deploy airflow on EC2 instances with docker/airflow images. T3.medium will suffice. Usually with not too many DAGs. We can create a workflow that will run after every 7 days and clean up the log files, So in terms of disk it won't be a problem if the memory consumption remains constant. You can install and configure an airflow normally on ec2 as you do in your local computer, but I prefer setting it up with docker image by puckel [here](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow).

First, you can either use AMI having docker installed or install it yourself.

Next, pull the image from the docker

```
docker pull puckel/docker-airflow
```

Here, you might get problem with SQLAlchemy version conflit(if not ignore this step. So change this line in `DockerFile` to use another version of airflow, higher like 1.10.10

```
ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.10.9 # change this to 1.10.10 ( or hardcode sqlalchmy version)
```

Next, you may need to add a user in postgres.

Now you can run it as

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 puckel/docker-airflow webserver
```

In order to enter command line (for starting the `executor`,`scheduler` etc), grab the container name/id from

```
docker ps
```

and use this command

```
docker exec -ti <name_of_container> bash
```

Also, in order to mount the ec2 folder with docker dags folder, you can mount it like below and your dags will be synced with airflow dags

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v /path/to/dags/on/your/ec2/folder/:/usr/local/airflow/dags  puckel/docker-airflow webserver
```

**In order to access this in browser from any other computer (you own laptop)**

First, enable `ec2` `http` port `8080` from security group for your IP

and from browser, you would be able to access it as

```
<ec2-public-ip>:8080
```

**Other third party managed option to run airflow on AWS**

[Astronomer](https://www.astronomer.io/pricing/) is a company that provides Fully hosted Airflow on all cloud platforms with advanced features of monitoring etc. They have some of the top Airflow contributes in their team

Cost:

Monthly cost for running Airflow for whole month on t3.medium will be around 32.37 USD and can be [calculated here](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)

Astronomer cost around [100$/month](https://www.astronomer.io/pricing/) per 10 AU(1 CPU, 3.75 GB memory) (but there are trade offs, its manage by astronomer and they provide support etc)

Answer (score 4):

You need install airflow on EC2 machine to manage all this requests of your EMR cluster.

Follow airflow installation

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/installation.html

You can check all airflow executors here -

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/executor/index.html

I recommend you to install celery executor for that.
On your EC2 machine you shall install at least 3 services from airflow

airflow webserver - To access airflow user interface
`airflow webserver start`

airflow scheduler - To trigger your dags
`airflow scheduler start`

airflow worker - to run your tasks
`airflow worker start`

Also extremely recommended to you install database (mysql, postgres) to store metadata from airflow. It`s possible to you run this database outside from EC2 machine as AWS RDS Postgres, then you can edit airflow.cfg file with connection string info of your database.